# how to write program for area for circle and square

Tags: python

Write a program that asks the user to enter two values: an integer choice and a real number x. If choice is 1, compute and display the area of a circle of radius x. If choice is 2, compute and display the are of a square with sides of length x. If choice is neither 1, nor 2, will display the text Invalid choice.

so im guessing this is broken into 2 parts? all i can think of so far is having a choice(input) function and defining what pi and area and so on are. but i keep getting errors. what am i doing wrong?

```
choice = input ('Enter Choice:')
choice_1 = int (choice)
if (choice_1==1): radius = (int)
print('Enter x:',radius)
pi = 3.14159
area = ( radius ** 2 ) * pi
print ( 'The Area is=' , area )
choice_2= (choice)
if (choice_2==2): side= (int)
print('enter X:' side*side)
```

Answer (score 3):

While you've got the actual calculations right, there are some problems with how you're receiving input. You start out well:

```
choice = input ('Enter Choice:')
```

But then do this:

```
choice_1 = int (choice)
```

That's not *wrong*, but there's no need for a new variable name. You could just as well do `choice = int(choice)`.

You then go on:

```
if (choice_1==1): radius = (int)
```

The `if` statement is okay (although the parentheses are not necessary), but the body of it is a bit strange. I don't know what you're trying to achieve there, but it's almost certainly not doing what you want. What you'll probably want to do is remove the current body of the `if` statement and indent a bunch of the following code.

```
print('Enter x:',radius)
```

This will print out `Enter x:` followed by `radius`, which you just set to the `int` function (probably not what you want. Instead, you probably want to prompt the user and receive their input:

```
radius = input('Enter x: ')
```

And then convert it to a float:

```
radius = float(radius)
```

Back to your code. `pi = 3.14159` is valid and correct, but there is no need to assign `pi` in your own code; just import it from `math`:

```
from math import pi
```

Then you've got these two lines:

```
area = ( radius ** 2 ) * pi
print ( 'The Area is=' , area )
```

You've got no problem there; those should work fine. Your code continues:

```
choice_2= (choice)
```

This is not useful. Just use `choice`; you don't need a new variable.

```
if (choice_2==2): side= (int)
```

The `if` statement, here, too, is correct, but its body, too, is senseless. Again, you probably want to prompt the user to enter something and then convert it to a float.

At the end, you've got:

```
print('enter X:' side*side)
```

First of all, you're missing a comma. Second of all, you're outputting the area after `enter X:`, which doesn't make that much sense. That said, you did get the calculation right.

Comment: Telling someone that something "doesn't make much sense" doesn't correct their misunderstanding. It doesn't make sense to you, but I'm fairly certain it made sense to the OP (i.e., if the computer reads the words 'enter x' it means to prompt the user for input--which we both know is incorrect thinking). Explaining *why* it "doesn't make sense" would be more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues with the code. Here is a working example of what I believe you want to accomplish:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
pi = 3.14159265

choice = input('Enter Choice [1 or 2]:')
choice = int (choice)

if choice == 1:
  radius = input('Enter x:')
  area = ( radius ** 2 ) * pi
  print 'The Area is=', area

if choice == 2:
  side = input('Enter x:')
  area = side ** 2
  print 'The Area is=', area
```

There are a number of problems with the code you've presented: indentation, variables, inputs, and outputs. There are a number of improvements that can be made as well (such as removing duplicate statements). The code I've given above will accomplish what you want to do. So let's go through the errors to get a deeper understanding.

### Indentation

First, Python programs should be indented properly. This means that lines following a conditional logic (such as an `if` statement) should be tabbed. The indentation is called a "block" statement. Only those lines that are indented will be evaluated (executed) if the given condition is met (e.g., the user supplied `1` or `2` as a value).

### Variables

The `choice_1` and `choice_2` variables are not necessary. Logistically, you want to tell the reader of your source code that the user's input should be rounded to a whole integer. The extra variables are superfluous -- you can reuse the `choice` variable.

### Inputs

The `input` function is used to assign the value of whatever the user typed to the variable on the left-hand-side of the expression. Examples:

```
choice = input ('Enter choice:')
radius = input( 'Enter x:' )
side = input( 'Enter x:' )
```

These `input` statements appear on the screen. The user types in a number and the value of that number is put inside the corresponding variable.

### Outputs

The `print` statement is used to display a value on the screen. In your code, you had combined a text string (`'Enter x'`) with a `print` statement. The computer cannot "know" that `'Enter x'` means that the user must type in a value. Just like the computer does not know that `'Barney'` is the name of a purple dinosaur.

Comment: @Droogans: No. The best way to learn is to dissect working code. Code that doesn't work (1) doesn't answer the question; (2) would reflect poorly on my answer; and (3) would not help the OP as much as a correct answer. Also, the original way I wrote the code deliberately avoided an import statement because the OP might not know what they do (i.e., it hides information). Similarly, adding "elif" code also introduces possibly another unknown that is not thoroughly explained.

Comment: I agree 100% with not giving deliberately broken code, but you might actually have done so unintentionally - in particular, OP appears to be using Python 3 - cf `print` as a function and passing the result of `input` through `int`.

Answer (score 2):

radius = (int)

This seems to be the main problem.

Comment: so far from what i understand i give the user 2 options, 1 or 2. you enter 1, you get to multiply a number with area of a circle, if 2 area of a square. so far it says error line 6 when i enter and other stuff. i just erased most of what i had. i think i have a bad comparison and dont define how to get the eqation stuff right.

Comment: check the code below and pay close attention to how they're different

the main problem is your trying to 'warn' python that the radius will be an integer

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

If that is how your script is indented, it's not going to work, period. Indenting is core to python, and you need to understand that before you'll get *anything* substantial working.

If the input is an integer, it will be automatically converted using `input()`. You're only asking for input once, so don't both creating two variables.

```
choice = input('Enter choice: ')
```

If should be using an `if-elif-else` statement here. Use control structures to your advantage:

```
if choice == 1:
  radius = input('Enter radius: ')
  print('Area of circle is ', (radius ** 2) * 3.14159)
elif choice == 2:
  side = input('Enter side length: ')
  print('Areas of square is ', side*side)
```

That's simplified, what you're trying to acheive.

Other than that, you shouldn't do `side= (int)` or `radius = (int)`. You're assigning a **type** of int to the variable, when you should be getting a value from input. You'll find very quickly that there are no operators that support multiplication of `type and type`.

Comment: The indentation in the OP will actually work, if probably not the way they mean - you can stuff immediately after the `:` of an `if` (or others) and it counts as part of the block.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It would work, but still deserves a bitch slap